# Can I specify my own encryption key in DTLS-SRTP encryption

Tags: encryption, webrtc, dtls

In my webrtc web app in Chrome, I used to specify my own encryption key by overriding the crypto information in the SDP. I am now migrating my webrtc web app to use DTLS-SRTP for encryption. With DTLS enabled, is there a way to tell Chrome which encryption key to send to the other client?

Answer (score 4):

No you cannot specify your own keys since the actual keys are sent over a secure media connection and are not part of the SDP.