# WebRTC SRTP decryption

Tags: encryption, webrtc, rtp, des, dtls

I am trying to build an `SRTP` to `RTP` stream converter and I am having issues getting the `Master Key` from the `WebRTC peerconnection` I am creating.

From what I understand, with a [DES exchange](http://www.cisco.com/web/about/security/intelligence/securing-voip.html), the key is exchange via the `SDP` exchange and is shown in the `a=crypto` field. So, this situation seems pretty straight forward(please correct me if I am wrong), but ultimately useless as `WebRTC` standardization is now demanding that DES should not be used(only `Chrome` supports it now and it may be removed in the future).

For [DTLS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347#section-4.2) there is the fingerprint field in the `SDP`, is that a hash of the [certificate desired](https://www.ietf.org/proceedings/68/slides/rtpsec-0.pdf) to be utilized in the future exchange?[EDIT: After doing some reading, I am thinking that that is not the case] I would think with knowledge of the fingerprint along side the ability to parse through the DTLS packets in the exchange I should be able to grab the `Master Key` to decode the SRTP stream, but I am hitting a wall as I do not know where to look or even 100% sure if it is possible.

So, in short, is it even feasible(without getting into the lower C++ API and creating my own implementation of `WebRTC`) to decode the `SRTP` feed that is created with a `WebRTC PeerConnection` in `Chrome` and `FireFox`(possibly through packet sniffing with the information gleaned from the `SDP` exchange)?[EDIT: depressingly, it seems that access to the private part of the key(aka, the master key) is not possible...please correct if I am wrong]

Comment: Related: [Can I specify my own encryption key in DTLS-SRTP encryption](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921946/can-i-specify-my-own-encryption-key-in-dtls-srtp-encryption)

Comment: I believe the only option currently is to use the native API and not the main stream browser implementations

Comment: With the library support from the accepted answer, were you able to finally convert SRTP to RTP (unencrypted)? I am also interested in this approach to implement my WebRTC SFU, but don't know where to start. Have asked few questions with bounties to no luck. See if you can help: [How to use libsrtp or similar library to decrypt/encrypt the WebRTC data stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71028698) and [How to integrate part of WebRTC...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71107066) If there is any library for SRTP to RTP, then would love to use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tHere is some code using openssl and libsrtp native api

```
#define SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN 16
#define SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN 14
static void dtls_srtp_init( struct transport_dtls *dtls )
{

/*
  When SRTP mode is in effect, different keys are used for ordinary
   DTLS record protection and SRTP packet protection.  These keys are
   generated using a TLS exporter [RFC5705] to generate

   2 * (SRTPSecurityParams.master_key_len +
        SRTPSecurityParams.master_salt_len) bytes of data

   which are assigned as shown below.  The per-association context value
   is empty.

   client_write_SRTP_master_key[SRTPSecurityParams.master_key_len];
   server_write_SRTP_master_key[SRTPSecurityParams.master_key_len];
   client_write_SRTP_master_salt[SRTPSecurityParams.master_salt_len];
   server_write_SRTP_master_salt[SRTPSecurityParams.master_salt_len];
*/
  int code;
  err_status_t     err;
  srtp_policy_t policy;
  char dtls_buffer[SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN * 2 + SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN * 2];
  char client_write_key[SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN + SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN];
  char server_write_key[SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN + SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN];
  size_t offset = 0;

  /*
   The exporter label for this usage is "EXTRACTOR-dtls_srtp".  (The
   "EXTRACTOR" prefix is for historical compatibility.)
   RFC 5764 4.2.  Key Derivation
  */
  const char * label = "EXTRACTOR-dtls_srtp";

  SRTP_PROTECTION_PROFILE * srtp_profile= SSL_get_selected_srtp_profile( dtls->ssl );

/* SSL_export_keying_material exports a value derived from the master secret,
 * as specified in RFC 5705. It writes |olen| bytes to |out| given a label and
 * optional context. (Since a zero length context is allowed, the |use_context|
 * flag controls whether a context is included.)
 *
 * It returns 1 on success and zero otherwise.
 */
  code = SSL_export_keying_material(dtls->ssl, 
                                    dtls_buffer, 
                                    sizeof(dtls_buffer),
                                    label, 
                                    strlen( label),
                                    NULL,
                                    0, 
                                    PJ_FALSE);

  memcpy(&client_write_key[0], &dtls_buffer[offset], SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN);
  offset += SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN;
  memcpy(&server_write_key[0], &dtls_buffer[offset], SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN);
  offset += SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN;
  memcpy(&client_write_key[SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN], &dtls_buffer[offset], SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN);
  offset += SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN;
  memcpy(&server_write_key[SRTP_MASTER_KEY_KEY_LEN], &dtls_buffer[offset], SRTP_MASTER_KEY_SALT_LEN); 

  switch( srtp_profile->id )
  {
  case SRTP_AES128_CM_SHA1_80:
    crypto_policy_set_aes_cm_128_hmac_sha1_80(&policy.rtp);
    crypto_policy_set_aes_cm_128_hmac_sha1_80(&policy.rtcp);
    break;
  case SRTP_AES128_CM_SHA1_32:
    crypto_policy_set_aes_cm_128_hmac_sha1_32(&policy.rtp);   // rtp is 32,
    crypto_policy_set_aes_cm_128_hmac_sha1_80(&policy.rtcp);  // rtcp still 80
    break;
  default:
    assert(0);
  }
  policy.ssrc.value = 0;
  policy.next = NULL;

  /* Init transmit direction */
  policy.ssrc.type = ssrc_any_outbound;  
  policy.key = client_write_key;    

  err = srtp_create(&dtls->srtp_ctx_rx, &policy);
  if (err != err_status_ok) {
    printf("not working\n");
  } 

  /* Init receive direction */
  policy.ssrc.type = ssrc_any_inbound;  
  policy.key = server_write_key;    

  err = srtp_create(&dtls->srtp_ctx_tx, &policy);
  if (err != err_status_ok) {
    printf("not working\n");
  } 

}
```

Comment: dude, love it! Is this part of a particular project?

Comment: Tanks, bwtrent! 
It's a part of CrystalVu SDK (http://www.integrit.com/products/240-crystalvu-video-conferencing-sdk) providing interoperability with sipml5 (http://sipml5.org/)

Answer (score 4):

I found 'SSL_export_keying_material'
Which can take a key from SSL mechanism (after DTLS handshake) and use it for SRTP.

I am not an expert, Just hitting the wall like you...

Answer (score 4):

It's not clear if this is your case, but note it's not possible to access the audio/video from (i.e.:unencrypt) the SRTP merely being a passive observer - that's the whole point of having transport encryption.

The protocol (DTLS-SRTP) works roughly like this:

- each browser has a unique keypair, usually generated on installation time
- The [fingerprint of the public part of the keypair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) of each side in included in the SDP, in the offer and answer.
- Both ends negotiate a DTLS connection, through a [ordinary DTLS handshake](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4347), thus deriving a kind of session key, which is used to secure the (DTLS) connection
- [The derived session key is used as the SRTP key](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5764#section-4.2)

If you don't have access to at least one of the private parts of the keypairs, it's not possible at all to decrypt the connection. If the endpoints choose to use a [Diffie-Hellman key exchange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman_key_exchange) on the handshake, a passive attacker will not be able to get the derived key, even with access to both private keys. This property is called [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

The only reliable way of accessing the SRTP contents is doing the handshake yourself, implementing a active MITM (changing the fingerprints on the SDP) or getting the private key from the browser and restricting DH key-exchange (which, AFAIK, is not possible at all)